# Is a mySQL relational database scalable for holding 80 GBs of additional logs per day?

Tags: mysql, logging

I am currently deciding on a long term architecture solution for storing DNS logs. The amount of data we are talking about numbers some 80 GBs of logs per day at the peak. Currently I am looking at noSQL databases such as mongoDB, as well as relational - mySQL. I want to structure a solution that has three requirements:

- Storage: This is a long term project, so I want the necessary capability to store 80 GBs of logs per day (~30 TB a year!). I realize this is pretty ridiculous, so I'm willing to have a retention period (keep 6 months' worth of logs = 15 TB constant).
- Scalability: As it is a long term solution, this is a big issue. I've heard that mongoDB is horizontally scalable, while mySQL is not? Any elaboration on this would be very well received.
- Query speed: As close to instantaneous querying as possible.

It should be noted that our logs are stored on an intermediary server, so we do not need to forward logs from our dns servers.

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions relating to programming topics only. For questions relating to database administration and configuration please use [dba.stackexchange.com](dba.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: How many rows is that?

Comment: I've not tried it, but I understand that MySQL is indeed horizontally scalable (it scales out better than PostgreSQL, which apparently scales better upwards). Have you looked at sharding? What sort of queries would you be issuing that require instantaneous responses? Lookups on indexed fields, like a PK, will be (relatively) fast. I wonder if you might need to do some solid testing here - import a large number of logs on a capable test server or dev machine, and play around with some architectures.

Comment: If you plan to look up just by IP, that would be very shardable - you take three bits from the IP's binary representation and map that onto 8 servers, for example.